# Reporting Services Error - enabling Remote Errors

Tags: reporting-services

So this has been bothering me for the last couple hours. I've created and deployed 2 reports on the server, with one of them being a drilldown. I have a javascript set up to open the drilldown in a new window whenever an item is selected. Instead of working as intended, I get this error:

```
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

Now I know what you're thinking, "Just set the remote errors to True and it should go away." The thing is, I can open the drilldown report separately and it works perfectly fine. I've had colleagues test the link as well, and they can drilldown on the report just fine. I've used different reports to test the action, to go to URL, and that works as well besides that one report. I've deleted the reports from the server and re-deployed them, but still no good. The reports I've tested are on the same datasource as the report I'm trying to get to work. It might be a permission issue, but I was the one who created and deployed the reports on to the server, so that's what I don't understand.

To summarize, my action to go to URL will work for everyone else but me, and the action to go to URL will work for every report but the one I need it to. Any insight or suggestions for a fix would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you try and run the report on the server where the report is hosted?

Comment: No, it comes up with the same error whenever I try and open it.

Comment: What does the error say? Running the report on the server that it is hosted on should show the errors that are occurring.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had meant something else. Are you referring to the report server or remote server? It shows the same error when I try to open it on the report server. When I did it on the remote server, it worked.

Comment: Okay just figured it out, I'm not sure why, but clearing the cookies and any temporary files worked. Not sure why though, maybe it just kept accessing old data.

Comment: Strange one! Glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, clearing my cookies, history, and temporary files seem to have worked. Maybe it was trying to access old data or something.